# XeLaTeX, Latin Modern, \mathbb and \mathcal

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode-math

I'm using XeLaTeX on Linux. I know that Latin Modern Roman is the default font of XeLaTeX, however if in my preamble I write

```
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
```

I get errors like

```
The font "Latin Modern Roman" cannot be found \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}.
```

I really do not understand what is the name of this defaul character.
Then, I use unicode-math package: my preamble is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
%\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
%\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
% \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
```

I don't like default \mathbb and \mathcal font of XeLaTeX. I noticed that, if I remove unicode-math I get the correct symbols. How to continue using unicode-math and having AMS font fot \mathbb and \mathcal?

Comment: Please provide a complete example we can compile. Note that `fontspec` enables Latin Modern for text by default. There is no need to set the serif. sans and mono as you do. I imagine that these fonts may not be installed for your system generally, which is necessary in order to use their names in this way with `fontspec`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why Latin Modern Roman is not recognized, perhaps it's not correctly installed as a system font.

For getting the “traditional” calligraphic and blackboard fonts you can use the standard setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % should go before unicode-math
%\usepackage{fontspec} % already loaded by unicode-math
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}
\setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\let\mathbb\relax % remove the definition by unicode-math
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

abc \textsf{def} \texttt{ghi}

$a+b\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathcal{ABC}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that it accets only file name (like *.otf) but not the name of the character. How can I proceed?

Comment: @MaPo Actually Latin Modern is chosen by default, so you can just leave all `\set...font` instructions off.

Comment: Why if I use $\bar{\mathcal{Q}}$ I get an error message. Is there a way to get the correct result?

Comment: @MaPo Sorry, only an ugly workaround.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way to use exactly the same fonts?

Comment: If you accept the ugly workaround… I wouldn't be too attached to the precise shape, though.

Comment: @egreg if  default fonts are not decleared expictly, macros from `fontspec` like `\addfontfeatures`  seems like not to work. Anything to deal with it?

Comment: @lyl You cannot add features to the default font.