# Use amssymb glyph with unicode-math

Tags: unicode-math

I want to use the `\mathbb{R}` glyph from **amssymb** with **unicode-math**. However, AFAIK **unicode-math** automatically loads TeX Gyre fonts for this glyph:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}

\begin{document}
\[\mathbb{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

How can I get the look I am used to (**pdfLaTeX** + **amssymb**)?

Comment: Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307755/52406) help?

Comment: Why do you think **unicode-math** loads the TeX Gyre fonts to be used for `\mathbb{R}`? Looking at the _.sty_ file **unicode-math** requires **amsmath** to be loaded, but I can't find a reference to the Gyre fonts nor to `\mathhbb` in the style file.

Comment: @alchemist I might be wrong and these are just Latin Modern glyphs.

Comment: @mickep Yes it does.

Comment: Doesn't matter ;-). Was just wondering if your statement was correct. Glad the suggestion of @mickep solved your question.

Comment: Yes, I know @DavidCarlisle. But that is not what I was referring to. It was the line *AFAIK ... automatically loads ... *  in the question that caught my eye.

Comment: Lol ... then I am correct @DavidCarlisle. I am not **saying** that `\symbb` comes from TeX Gyre, but **asking** _why_  the OP thinks that.